# xlwings context manager invoking pywintypes.com_error when invoking app.kill()

Tags: python, excel, pandas, numpy, xlwings

The code below has a lot more functionality within it, but its basic xlwings open, save and close functionality still invokes pywintypes.com_error: (-2147023170, 'The remote procedure call failed.', None, None). Please help as I have tried a multitude of solutions and have yet to find one that works.

```
import xlwings as xw

def manipulation():
       with xw.App(visible=True) as app:
          wb = xw.Book(filePath)
          sheet = wb.sheets['SheetName']
          wb.save(path)
          wb.close()
          app.kill()
```

If anyone could help me out, or if you need more of the code please let me know. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The whole point of the context manager is that you don't need to quit the app manually anymore (and it's even going to be properly cleaned up if there's an exception happening before the end of the function. So simply leave away the `kill` (it's part of the context manager if there's a need for it). You should also make sure to use the `app` object and not rely on the active app by doing `app.books` instead of using `xw.Book`. Edit: also leave away the `wb.close()` as xlwings requires at least one workbook open to be able to talk to Excel. It will be automatically closed by the app context manager.

```py
import xlwings as xw

def manipulation():
    with xw.App(visible=True) as app:
       wb = app.books.open(filePath)
       sheet = wb.sheets['SheetName']
       wb.save(path)
```

Comment: Hey Felix, thanks for your response! I tested it out and it ended up creating a zombie process of Excel. I had my visibility set to false on the first run and currently running it again but visible. Will update in ~40 minutes

Comment: Remove `wb.close()` to see if that makes a difference, but using the app context manager definitely first does `app.quit()` and then tries to `app.kill()` just in case it wasn't able to properly close it. Make sure you're on a recent version though.

Comment: Trying now, the last attempt with it visible ended up invoking the same error

Comment: That worked! Just needed to get rid of the `wb.close()` and `app.kill()`. Accepting your answer as the solution, and thank you again for your help!

Comment: Great, thanks for confirming. Updated my answer accordingly.